# grep exact word from input file

Tags: grep

My input files:

1. text.txt - The file to be searched
2. patterns.txt - File containing a list of words (one word per line) that are to be searched for in the text.txt file.

text.txt is:

```
abc     def     ghi
jkl     mno     pqr ; stu
zzz     yyy     xxx
jkl     abs     abc1 ; mno
jjj     aaa     abc1M1
```

and pattern.txt is:

```
abc
pq
abc1M1
```

If I do:

```
| => grep -f patterns.txt text.txt
abc def ghi
jkl mno pqr ; stu
jkl abs abc1 ; mno
jjj aaa abc1M1
```

However, only two lines should be returned:

```
abc def ghi
jjj aaa abc1M1
```

i.e. only those lines that match the complete words "abc" and "abc1M1" as given in the patterns.txt file. How should I structure my query?

thanks for your help!

Edit: Suggestion from Cyrus to try '-Fwf' option, but it still doesn't give me what I want to get:

```
| => grep -Fwf patterns.txt text.txt
abc def ghi
```

Also, I am running the grep on my mac:

```
| => grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Fwf pattern.txt text.txt
```

Output:

```
abc     def     ghi
jjj     aaa     abc1M1
```

> `-F`:             Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.

> `-w`:              Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words.

---

See: `man grep`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I try that, I get: | => grep -Fwf patterns.txt text.txt
abc def ghi ...see edit in main post for formatted output

Comment: Check both files for special characters: `cat -A filename` or `cat -v filename`

Comment: I checked with 'cat -v patterns.txt' and 'cat -v text.txt', but there were no special characters. The output was exactly the same as the files are shown in the main post.

Comment: Aha! Downloaded and installed the GNU grep, and everything seems to work now. Thanks for all your help!!